# JavaScript Buy SDK - Shopify

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I'm using JavaScript buy SDK with Node.js.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const shopify = require('shopify-buy');

const client = shopify.buildClient({
  storefrontAccessToken: 'MY_STORE_ACCESS_TOKEN',
  domain: 'SHOP_URL',
}, fetch);
```

I'm getting a product ID like this:

```
const products = yield client.product.fetchAll();
const variantId = products[0].variants[0].id;
const checkout = yield client.checkout.create();
```

Is there any method to add this product into cart using JavaScript Buy SDK, in the documentation they have specified that this SDK can be used to add a product to the cart too!

Answer (score 2):

The following example code is taken from [the docs](https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/#adding-line-items)

```
const checkoutId = 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0SW1hZ2UvMTgyMTc3ODc1OTI='; //  ID of an existing checkout
const lineItemsToAdd = [
  {variantId: 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC8yOTEwNjAyMjc5Mg==', quantity: 5}
];
// Add an item to the checkout
client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd).then((checkout) => {
  // Do something with the updated checkout
  console.log(checkout.lineItems); // Array with one additional line item
});
```

Comment: Hello Stefan, thanks for your reply!
Can you just tell me after calling this API, will the item be added visually to the cart of the user?

Comment: Yes and no. You code backend/serverside, isn't it. This simply adds line items (products) to the users carts (checkout). Users will see changes with next visit/reload of the cart. At least, it is my understanding. Still reading and did not code much myself.

Comment: how do you refetch the line items if you save the checkout id in local storage, and reload the page?. Let-s say I add a line item of value 150. Then I save the checkout id in localstorage. I go to shopify admin site and I change the price to that item to 170. Then, I reload the page fetching the checkout by id using that id in local storage. The total of the checkout object is still 150, how do I fix that and do a whole refetch of the checkout?